# Modificar respuesta Middleware Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Saben como puedo modificar la respuesta "message": "Unauthenticated." que por defecto me da el middleware de Laravel cuando el usuario no esta autenticado en la API?

Este es el codigo de mi ruta.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::post('insert_demo','ApiReservationsController@insert_demo');
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para modificar el texto, debes crear un override en tu proyecto del Middleware Authenticate, o también puedes crear tu propia versión (pero debes traer todo el código respectivo) el cual está ubicado en

> vendor/laravel/framework/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php

En el método authenticate de dicho middleware encuentras el texto que deseas reemplazar:

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is logged in to any of the given guards.
 *
 * @param  array  $guards
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
 */
protected function authenticate(array $guards)
{
    if (empty($guards)) {
        return $this->auth->authenticate();
    }
    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
            return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
        }
    }
    throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.', $guards);
}
```

Una vez hayas hecho el override o creado tu propia versión, no olvides modificar el archivo app/Http/Kernel.php, más exactamente en la propiedad/atributo $routeMiddleware a algo como esto:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'              => Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ...
```